# displayed ngFor data in a new container div when the length get to four

Tags: html, angular

I need a little help getting to display my ngFor data in a new container div when the length gets to four. hard coding the data in several div is easier, but using ngFor displays the data in a single container div.

the code below there is supposed to be four **book-section-subGrid DIV** in a **book-section-grid DIV**

**My attempt**

```
<div class="book-section-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let book of books" class="book-section-subGrid">
      <img src="assets/images/book1-1.png" alt="">
      <h4>{{book?.title}}</h4>
      <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What i want to achieve**

```css
.book-section-grid {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1st Section -->
<div class="book-section-grid">
  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2nd Section -->
<div class="book-section-grid">
  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="book-section-subGrid">
    <img height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
    <h4>Photographer’s trouble shooter</h4>
    <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are u looking for?

Comment: Why not using "book" index? and then you can *ngIf when it's equal\larger than 4

Comment: throw more light please

Comment: what exactly you required

Comment: Just use `https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch`.

Comment: My question has just been edited for a better explanation, please review. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 <div class="book-section-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let book of books; let index = index;" class="book-section-subGrid">
        <div *ngIf="index < 5; else elseBlock">
          <h4>{{book?.title}}</h4>
          <img  height="100" width="100" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
          <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
        </div>
        <ng-template #elseBlock>
          <h1>{{book?.title}}</h1>
          <img  height="50" width="50"src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
          <span>by <a href="#">Michael Freeman</a></span>
        </ng-template>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: here is working stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjwuts

Comment: Thanks, we're getting close to the solution. Please check out my edited question to get a better understanding, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of angular [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe).

You can find a sample implementation [here](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe).

Comment: My question has just been edited for a better explanation, please review. Thanks